# Surface integral evaluation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find$$\iint_S xdy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+z^4 dx\wedge dy$$ where $S$ is
>   part of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, bounded above by $z=1$, downward
>   oriented.

I think that the integral is equal to $\iint_{\partial S}2+4z^3,$ $\partial S=\{x^2+y^2=1, z=1\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You are not using Stoke's theorem correctly. Please notice that you just write $\int_S w = \int_{\partial S} dw$ which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I remember Stoke's is by way of the fact that if $M$ has dimension $n$, then $\partial M$ has dimension $n-1$, assuming $M$ has boundary. If we take the exterior derivative of a $n$-form say $\omega$, it becomes a $n+1$ form. Therefore, the integration of $d\omega$ over $\partial M$ doesn't make sense, so it must be the other way around which is,

$$\int_{\partial M} \omega =  \int_{M} d \omega$$

Comment: how do I apply the theorem in this particular problem? Because $S$ doesn't seem a boundary of something to me

Comment: You can't,  unless you can show the form you have is exact i.e if you say $\tau$ is your form above and you know $\omega$ such that $d\omega = \tau$ then you can apply the theorem.

Comment: then how should I tackle the problem? I tested a few possible forms but cannot show $w$ is exact

Comment: Parametrize $S$ by $f: D \to S$ and so, $$\int_S \tau = \int_D f^* \tau$$ but make sure $f$ induces the clockwise orientation on the boundary curve since you said you are using the inward (downward) pointing normal vector. You can check this computing $f_u \times f_v = \pm N$ where $N$ is the inward normal. Make sure you get $+$.

Comment: Did you get anywhere?

Comment: I used $f(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and I see that $f$ points upward, so it defines the opposite orientation(I guess). The remaining part is to find $\int_U w(f)$ and take negative value(Is this right?). Thanks for your time by the way!

Comment: Okay, so I think you can get the right one by letting $t = -x$ and take $f(t,y) = (t,y, \sqrt{t^2+y^2})$. I don't know what you mean by $w(f)$, you need to compute the pull back $f^*(\omega)$. For instance, if $\omega = 2x dx \wedge dy$ then  $f^*(2x dx \wedge dy) = 2 \cdot x(f) \ d(x \circ f) \wedge d(y \circ f)$.